# How to get the selected value from dropdown list and past it to sql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have two dropdown list box,first one is sales area contain different kind of alphabet which get from cookie,second dropdown staff name is to change according to the selected value from first dropdown. How can i manage to pass the selected option value to my sql query so that it can be change according to the selected sales area.
[This is the results that i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN07F.png) I insert my code to the snippet for easy to do edit and demonstration.

```js
function fetch_select(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'updateleave.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("slct2").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
```

```html
<table >
 <tr>
     
     <td>  Sales Area 
  <select name="Area" id="area" >
        <?php
   
        $sarea = explode(",",$_COOKIE['cooAreaCode']);
        foreach($sarea as $item){
  
        ?>
        <option   value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
  
        <?php
  
        }
   


 
        ?>
       
       </select >
       </td>
    <?
        $var = $_POST['Area'];
   $sql = "SELECT  StaffName FROM tblStaff WHERE AreaCode= '$var'";
      $rs = odbc_exec($link,$sql);
  while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
   $porr[] = $row;
    }
    
   odbc_free_result($rs);   
  odbc_close($link); 
  ?>
     <td>  Staff Name 
  <select id="slct2">
    
        ?>
       
       </select>
    
       </td>
    <label class="form_field">Your selected <span id="aggregator_name"></span></label>
```

(updateleave.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['get_option'])) {
```

$item=$_POST['get_option'];

```
  $sql = "SELECT  StaffName FROM tblStaff WHERE AreaCode= '$item'";
  $rs = odbc_exec($link,$sql);
 while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
     $porr[] = $row;
   }
    for($i=0; $i < count($porr);$i++) {
   echo "<option  value="strtolower($porr[$i]['StaffName']);" >" .$porr[$i]['StaffName']."</option>";
  odbc_free_result($rs);   
 odbc_close($link); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in real time?  When I change the first drop down, the second drop down is immediately updated via an SQL call?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want man! any suggestion

Comment: you probably needed a dependent dropdown

Comment: Research AJAX and JSON. When the 1st drop-down is changed, you make an AJAX call to a script on your server when then returns the data for the second drop-down, and you put those options in the 2nd drop-down. jQuery makes this pretty easy. Lot's of example code around.

Comment: Can you give any suggestion or example on how to do it ,so that i can took it as a reference.

Comment: I have updated my work ,but it's still can get any work with my ajax ,does it possible got wrong with my ajax ?please give some suggestion thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use append to add option tags with in select tag also do all the work in change event of the first drop down ("#area")

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#area").change(function()
{
var val =$(this).val();
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'updateleave.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
$("#clct2").append(response);
}
 });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of jQuery, so you'll need to convert my Javascript to your needs, but what you need is to capture an onchange event for the first drop down and use it to dynamically process the SQL for the second dropdown.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('area').onclick = function(){
    var xmlhttp;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('area_value', this.value);
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // for DEBUGGING.
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'false'){
                            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    } else {
                            document.getElementById('slct2').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", 'build_slct2.php');
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    xmlhttp.onerror = function () { console.error(xmlhttp.statusText); }
}
</script>
```

The `build_slct2.php` script would use `$_POST['area_value']` to create the desired SQL query, process the query, and build the `<option></option>` list that will end up in the `slct2` drop down.  The `build_slct2.php` file would simply `echo` the new contents for `slct2`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , do i need to amend it become new jquery or straight way put it in my program ?

Comment: I have updated my works ,it's turn it into ajax function ,but it's doesn't seems work with my program

Comment: This will work.  You need to find out where the failure to pass is coming from.  I've added an `alert()` on line 13.  Have your `build_slct2.php` script simply `print_r($_POST); return;` to be sure the data you need to send it is arriving.  I've also added an `onerror` line that will print to the Javascript console to see if anything is going wrong with the Ajax code.

Comment: It shows an alert message Array{ area value =1} what does it means for ?this message come out when i click on the L .Did i do anything wrong?